# How to give navbar bottom a limit on its height on a page?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a rails app with a navbar bottom.  On the pages that don't have a lot of content it is placed very high on the page.  Is there a way to give it a max vertical value for it's location?  Say I want to keep the top of the bar at 750px.

Comment: what have u tried ? please paste here with example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put everything above your navbar in an enclosing div and give it a min-height in CSS.